# Form Validation PHP cleanups

Tags: php, forms, validation, post, swiftmailer

Here sample code of my project. I have a personal portfolio that is mostly a static page, running this simple PHP script to validate a form and to send a Email to the admin.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $flag = $_POST['FLAG'];
    $name = trim(stripcslashes($_POST['name']));
    $email = trim(stripcslashes($_POST['email']));
    $message = trim(stripcslashes($_POST['message']));
    $success = false;

    $mail = new Mail($flag, $name, $email, $message, $config);   

    $result = $mail->validateFields();

    if($result) {
        $errors = $result;
    } elseif ($result == false) {
        $mail->sendEmail();
        $success = true;
    }    
}
```

Any Idea how to improve my code?
I am using swiftmailer and a 3rd party MTA (mailgun).
The class MAIL has 2 methods : Validate and Send.
validate method is used to validates the fields and return false if no errors are found, else return an array with error messages.
The send mail is using swiftmailer to send a email. Any Idea how to make everything better? Should I change something or is pretty much ok?

```
class Mail
{
public $flag = null;
public $name = null;
public $email = null;
public $message = null;
public $config = null;
public $errors = [];

function __construct($flag, $name, $email, $message, $config)
{
    $this->flag = $flag;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->config = $config;

}

public function validateFields()
{   
    if (!empty($this->flag)) {
    $this->errors[] = 'SPAM FILTER ERROR =)';
    }

    if ( empty($this->name) | !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $this->name)) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Enter valid name';
    }

    if ( empty($this->email) | !filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
        $this->errors[] = 'Enter valid email address';
    }

    if ( empty($this->message) ) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Please enter a message';
    }

    if( empty($this->errors) ) {
        return false;

    } else {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}

public function sendEmail()
{
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport("{$this->config['SMTP']}", 25))
        ->setUsername("{$this->config['USERNAME']}")
        ->setPassword("{$this->config['PASSWORD']}");

    /// rest of email logic
}
}
```

Any Suggestions will be very appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `how to improve my code` is a very broad question..and the code you've posted is very minimal. Might be better off on code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: add some more details, but I will follow ur advice and post it in stackechange... never even heard from it! Thanks!